# Get all columns with groupby clickhouse

Tags: sql, join, select, count, clickhouse

I'm trying to get all columns in clickhouse for the students with number of questions greater than 1. What am I missing?

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 PREWHERE IDNUMBER IN (SELECT IDNUMBER, COUNT(QUESTIONS) as XXX FROM table_1 GROUP BY IDNUMBER HAVING XXX > 1)
```

This is the error I got:

```
DB::Exception: Number of columns in section IN doesn't match. 1 at left, 2 at right.: While executing MergeTreeThread
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery should return just one column, while it contains two:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_1 PRE
WHERE IDNUMBER IN (SELECT IDNUMBER FROM table_1 GROUP BY IDNUMBER HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: XXX is not defined in your case i.e., number of questions is not taken into consideration

Comment: @tandem: I changed that already. I used `COUNT(*)`, but if `QUESTIONS` is a nullable column you can change that to `COUNT(QUESTIONS)`.

Comment: QUESTIONS in this case is nullable. How does one handle if it is not nullable?

Comment: @tandem: if it is nullable, just replace `COUNT(*)` with `COUNT(QUESTIONS)` in the above queries.

Comment: my bad that I did not make it explicit. How do we handle if QUESTIONS is NOT nullable?  Correct me if I am wrong, COUNT(*) you would take into account all columns, and not necessarily QUESTIONS and thus if any column have count > 1, it would return it.

Comment: One more question: In the second query, why do we define the variable t?

Comment: @tandem: that's a table alias, that we can use to refer to the outer table in the subquery.

Comment: I figured that was the table alias. I think it was missed in the pre-updated answer. thanks for clarifying. with `t.IDNUMBER` it says the column name is missing. `t1.IDNUMBER` is found.
I found that dropping the table alias `table_1 t` and just having the condition as `t1.IDNUMBER = IDNUMBER` works.

Comment: @GMB CH does not support correlated subqueries. Moreover it will hit performance in case if you need to execute a subquery 10 billions time.

Comment: @DenisZhuravlev: ok my bad. So I guess we are left with the first option using `IN`! We could also join an aggregate query, couldn't we?

Comment: @GMB avoid joins as much as possible in case of CH . Only IN is usable in this case.

Comment: @DenisZhuravlev: ok. I removed the correlated subquery from my answer.